# Remove margin of ListView contained in an ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbaractivity

So I did an Activity that extends the ListActivity, and it worked fine, but then I found out that to make it work in old mobiles, it should extend ActionBarActivity instead, and when I turned it into that, theres a big margin surrounding my ListView. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was being caused by the following properties in the main.xml layout:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

So removing them fixed the problem, I assume the default margin must be 0dp.

Answer (score 0):

For the old mobiles, I think you can `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` and give it a try. For more details, head to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html Thanks.